# How to pass the value of a variable to another method in android

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have variable and it has a value. i want to pass it to another method so i can use it inside that. in `onCreate` i have the value for description and i want to pass that value to `prepareListData()`, so i can use it there. what should i do to achieve that.

```
String description;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.c_activity);

        String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");

        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add(description); //description = abcd
```

in a method i want to use the value of description,

```
private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add(description); //need to get 1234 here, but i get null

        // Adding child data
        List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
        description.add("The Shawshank"); 

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), description); // Header, Child
        // data

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        mExpandableList.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width
                - GetPixelFromDips(10));
    }
```

Comment: If the prepareListData() method is located in the same class (Activity class) you don't need to passa anything, you can directly access it. However you should be sure that `getIntent().getStringExtra("description");` does not return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually creating a local description value and trying to use global one inside the `prepareListData()` method.

So to solve the problem, You need to remove "String" from the `onCreate()` method
Change your code like below,

String description;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.c_activity);

    description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description"); // modified line

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add(description); //description = abcd
```